# Create a logic to check if viewModel == 0 & show <div> tag

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to show a  when checking model is 0. However, after creating a logic to check whether model is 0, i am getting white blank page. If the model is != 0 it is displaying the  with the model != 0

I have put a breakpoint debugger to check whether the the api is successfully called & everything works fine. The api is getting count = 0 if there is no premises in db & the count is != 0 if there is premises in db.

I have tried giving a div id to the  tag & style display = none so that it will be hidden by default & create a logic in script to check whether model is 0 then show the div with the id but it is still not working.

views.cshtml:

```
@model List<MyTNB.MyHome.Web.Areas.Application.Models.MyHomeChecklist.HMOPremisesViewModel>


<div class="px-md-5 px-4 mt-4">
    <div class="card-title-blue-20-16 mb-2 font-weight-bold">@Localizer.GetLocalizedString("HMO_ConnectToMyHome_MyPremises")</div>
</div>
@if (Model.Count == 0)
{
    <!--#region No Premises Card-->
    <div class="container-fluid default-spacing-24 mt-md-3">
        <div class="block block--light br-xs-0">
            <div class="no-premise-icon">
                <img src="~/assets/img/hmo-connectmyhome-no-premise-icon.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="no-premise-text card-title-inverse-lighter">
            @Localizer.GetLocalizedString("HMO_ConnectToMyHome_NoPremise_Desc")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--#endregion No Premises Card-->
}
else
{
    <div class="myhome-ul px-md-5 px-4 mb-2">
        <ul data-role="listview" id="tasks">
            <!--#region My Premises Card-->
            @foreach (var premise in Model)
            {
                <li class="mb-2">
                    <div class="wrapper" id="wrapper_@premise.PremisesID"
                            onmousedown="_taskCardMouseDown(event, @premise.PremisesID)"
                            onmouseup="_taskCardMouseUp(event, @premise.PremisesID)"
                            ontouchstart="_taskCardTouchStart(event, @premise.PremisesID)"
                            ontouchend="_taskCardTouchEnd(event, @premise.PremisesID)">
                        <div class="go" style="width:0%;"></div>
                        <div class="item" id="item_@premise.PremisesID">
                            <div class="block block--light block--cardShadow flex justify-content-between custom-radius mb-md-4 mb-2">
                                <div class="flex center">
                                    <div class="mr-3">
                                        <img src="~/assets/img/hmo-connectmyhome-home-icon.svg" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="text-left task-description" onclick="MyPremise('@premise.PremisesID.ToString()','@premise.ApplicationType')">
                                            @premise.PremiseNickname
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><div class="block block--light block--cardShadow flex justify-content-between edit" id="edit_@premise.PremisesID" onclick="EditPremise('@premise.PremisesID.ToString()','@premise.ApplicationType')"><img src="~/assets/img/edit-white.svg" /></div><div class="del block block--light block--cardShadow flex justify-content-between" id="del_@premise.PremisesID" onclick="openDelModal('@premise.PremisesID.ToString()')"><img class="" src="~/assets/img/delete-white.svg" /></div>
                    </div>
                </li>                              
            }
            <!--#endregion My Premises Card-->
        </ul>
    </div>
}
```

controller:

```
    [HttpGet("ConnectToMyHome")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ConnectToMyHome()
    {
        try
        {
            var premises = await _hmoHelper.GetHMOPremisesAsync();

            return View(premises);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home");
        }
    }
```

viewModel:

```
using System;

namespace MyTNB.MyHome.Web.Areas.Application.Models.MyHomeChecklist
{
    public class HMOPremisesViewModel
    {
        public Guid PremisesID { get; set; }
        public string PremiseNickname { get; set; }
        public string ApplicationType { get; set; }
        public string ApplicationID { get; set; }
        public int TaskType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

response:

```
    namespace MyTNB.MyHome.Web.Services.ApiModels.MyHomeChecklist
{
    public class GetHMOPremisesResponse : ApiResponseBody
    {
        public GetHMOPremisesViewModelContent Content { get; set; }
    }

    public class GetHMOPremisesViewModelContent
    {
        public List<HMOPremisesViewModel> Premises { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: No you should have count on index item instead of count or use `Model.Any()` which will check if the list is empty.

Comment: Why did you delete https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77843733/send-the-generated-file-to-client-for-download-asp-net ?

Comment: @Enigmativity let me try to fix the typos because my workspace is on RD so i need to type out my codes...might not notice the typos

Comment: On "RD"? What does that mean? Remote Desktop?

Comment: @Enigmativity yess on RD, im connected to vdi & then jumphost & my workspace is on another server....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to show a when checking model is 0. However, after
> creating a logic to check whether model is 0, i am getting white blank
> page. If the model is != 0 it is displaying the with the model != 0

Actually, `Model.Count` wouldn't help you get your desire result because in view we cannot count the overall model but its index element or items count in perticular. For instance, you can do like `Model.FirstOrDefault().YourModelElements` so if the list empty this block will not be executed.

However, the most easy and efficient way you can achieve that using [Model.Any()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-7.0) which will execute if block if the list not empty other than it will execute else block.

Let's have a look in practice:

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var countCheckModel = new List<HMOPremisesViewModel>
            {

                new HMOPremisesViewModel(){ PremisesID = new Guid(), PremiseNickname = "Microsoft",ApplicationType = "A", ApplicationID ="101",TaskType =1},
                new HMOPremisesViewModel(){ PremisesID = new Guid(), PremiseNickname = "Amazon",ApplicationType = "B", ApplicationID ="201",TaskType =2},
                new HMOPremisesViewModel(){ PremisesID = new Guid(), PremiseNickname = "Google",ApplicationType = "C", ApplicationID ="303",TaskType =2},
            };

            var emptyList = new List<HMOPremisesViewModel>();
            return View(countCheckModel);
        }
```

**Note:** For testing I am passing empty list at first time and then List with 3 items.

View:

```
@model List<DotNet6MVCWebApp.Controllers.HMOPremisesViewModel>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

@if(Model.Any())
{
    Console.WriteLine(Model.Count());
}
else{
   Console.WriteLine("else executed because model is zero");
}
```

Output:

[image]